# Ubuntu brand new installation in VM, with nginx permission issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, permissions, nginx

I built a fresh VM built from the std `Ubuntu 18/04 LTS x64 Server` image.

Installed updates, then installed `VBox Guest Additions` following the simple steps [outlined here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-a-gui-less-ubuntu-server-host/).

Installed nginx with:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

I check that the service is running;

```
papa@papa:~$ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-05-30 18:01:37 UTC; 14s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 823 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 783 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 832 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1112)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─832 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─840 nginx: worker process

May 30 18:01:37 papa systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 30 18:01:37 papa systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
May 30 18:01:37 papa systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Upon running `nginx -t` I get:

```
papa@papa:~$ nginx -t
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2018/05/30 18:02:09 [warn] 1234#1234: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2018/05/30 18:02:09 [emerg] 1234#1234: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

As this is a clean installation, why would `nginx` not have permissions it requires to write to the log? Also, why the `Failed to parse PID`? Did I miss a step somewhere?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in nginx See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=876365 Someone posted a workaround...